# How to Hide a component in angular but still pass in function from parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code:

```
<app-csv-confirm-dialog *ngIf="false" (confirmUpload)="addDataFromCSV()"></app-csv-confirm-dialog>

addDataFromCSV() {
  console.log('hi');
}
```

And then in the ts file for csv-confirm-dialog:

```
confirm(): void {
  this.confirmUpload.emit();
}
```

However seems like this does not work as I don't get console.log, is there anyway that I still could pass the function from the parent to the csv-confirm-dialog? (It has to be hidden since it's a popup dialog)

Comment: our question is not explanatory enough please elaborate

Comment: What's actually inside `ngIf` in your code? Is it just `false` for real?

Comment: Yes it has to be hidden, the show/hide of modal is in the function in the ts file

Comment: Can you share some more code or perhaps a stackblitz? It seems to me that if you don't want anything to display, then just leave the html of the child component blank. I guess I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

The component needs to be in the DOM for the event emitter to be handled. If not, you could remove the event emitter and use a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). Try the following

shared.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SharedService {
  private _confirmUploadSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public confirmUpload$ = this._confirmUploadSource.asObservable();

  public setUploadStatus(value: any) {
    this._confirmUploadSource.next(value);
  }
}
```

CsvConfirmDialog component

```js
export class CsvConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  confirm(value: any): void {
    this.sharedService.setUploadStatus(value);
  }
}
```

Parent component

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  completed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.confirmUpload$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$)
    ).subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log('hi');
        // do what you were going to do in `addDataFromCSV()` function
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.completed$.next();           // <-- close the observables
    this.completed$.complete();
  }
}
```